# Error: missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE

Tags: r, purrr

Trying out multiple models chapter of #r4ds and ran into an error message at the end:

> Error: missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In ns(as.numeric(Month), 4) : NAs introduced by coercion

with

```
ADA_model<- function(ADA_mutiple_model){
   lm(ADA ~ ns(as.numeric(Month), 4), data=ADA_mutiple_model)
}

ADA_mutiple_model <- ADA_mutiple_model %>% 
     mutate(model=map(data,ADA_model))
```

as the code I used that creates the error.

See mod3 below to see what the function looks like

[image]

Comment: You can't use `lm` if there are `NA` in your data. Therefore, the error message is straightforward : add the option `na.rm=TRUE` in `lm`. I suggest you look at your data as well to understand what is wrong with your data.

Comment: @jgadoury I don't think `lm` has a `na.rm` argument.  Could you mean the `na.action` argument?

Comment: The argument is `na.omit=TRUE`, my mistake

Comment: Yeah what the hell am I talking about, it's `na.action=na.omit`. That's what happens when I try to sound smart without double-checking my stuff

Comment: That is the right argument, but the problem was on my function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with the use of `lm`, but inside `splines::ns` when generating B-spline basis for natural cubic splines. **Very likely your `Month` is a character variable**, and you can not use `as.numeric` for coercing.

---

I just checked your attached figure. The x-axis in the plots verifies what I guessed. You need to use 1:12 for `Month`, not "JAN", "FEB", etc.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. I am wondering why that was because I was able to this earlier on the script

Comment: ```mod1 <- lm(median_ADA ~ ns(as.numeric(Month), 2), data = Summary_model)
mod2 <- lm(median_ADA ~ ns(as.numeric(Month), 3), data = Summary_model)
mod3 <- lm(median_ADA ~ ns(as.numeric(Month), 4), data = Summary_model)
mod4 <- lm(median_ADA ~ ns(as.numeric(Month), 5), data = Summary_model)

grid<-Summary_model %>% data_grid(Month=seq_range(as.numeric(Month), n=50, expand=0.1)) %>% 
  gather_predictions(mod1,mod2,mod3,mod4, .pred="median_ADA")

ggplot(Summary_model, aes(Month,median_ADA)) +
  geom_point()+
  geom_line(data = grid, colour="red")+
  facet_wrap(~ model) ```