# Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE

Tags: r, ggplot2, outliers

I am trying to assign labels to `ggplot2` outliers the way it is specified here:

[Labeling Outliers of Boxplots in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33524669/labeling-outliers-of-boxplots-in-r)

And to create a new `outlier` column I am using the following code:

```
splitData %>% 
  group_by(Sample.group) %>%
  mutate(outlier=ifelse(is_outlier(value), value, as.numeric(NA)))
```

And I am getting the error:

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
>     Evaluation error: missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE.

The `splitData` looks like that:

[image]

I guess, wrong `as.numeric()` happens somewhere; there is a similar thread:

[Error: missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38961475/error-missing-values-and-nans-not-allowed-if-na-rm-is-false)

But I am having trouble figuring out where. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please share your data using `dput()`. Seem more here:
[How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot turn NA values into a number by using `as.numeric(NA)`. You should omit the NA values or impute them if you can. Missing values are always a nuisance but sometimes there is nothing more left to do than dropping the samples (=rows in your case).

Comment: Okay, I saw the example for the boxplots (mtcars) and there it is used to add NA to a non-factor column (dbl formatted) during the ifelse statement. But did you source the function is_outlier? `is_outlier <- function(x) {
  return(x < quantile(x, 0.25) - 1.5 * IQR(x) | x > quantile(x, 0.75) + 1.5 * IQR(x))
}`